# Camera preview UI overlay on Android?

Tags: android, user-interface, camera, overlay, preview

How do I write code which layouts UI elements (Buttons, etc) over camera preview on Android ?

Answer (score 16):

Put the `SurfaceView` in a container that allows for Z-axis layering, such as `RelativeLayout` or `FrameLayout`. Put the things to appear on top of the `SurfaceView` later in the XML -- later children of a parent will draw over top of earlier children in the parent.

[Here is a project](http://github.com/commonsguy/vidtry) using a `SurfaceView` for video playback that demonstrates the technique. The same concepts should hold for a `SurfaceView` for camera preview.

Bear in mind that extra work needs to be done by Android to blend your widgets with the preview, so your preview frame rate may drop.